# Drag on Mouseover?! Jquery / UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want to start dragging on mouseover, not on click.

This means, I want to have a div, where I just want to mouseover and then it should be instantly dragged.

How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920473/how-to-bind-jquery-draggable-to-a-hover-event

Comment: Thanks, but its not dragging on mouseover, its still dragging on click but with axes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following in your mouse over:

```
$('#element_id').mouseover(function(){
    $('#element_id').trigger('mousedown');

    //Rest of dragging code here.   
});
```

So, this means you are creating fake mousedown instead of click and when you dragging point reached you can realise by triggering mouseup.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. Here is my code: $('.element').draggable();
    $('.element').mouseover(function() {
     $(this).trigger('click');
    });

Comment: I do not understand can you post your code into your question itself?

Answer (score 1):

I found this topic earlier, but I am not sure how it can be made without this simulate library.

[Initialize element and start dragging with just one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255788/initialize-element-and-start-dragging-with-just-one-click)

Maybe it will help someone else.

If someone knows how to solve this without this library, please tell me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think You want Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
isOvered=false;
function dragme(e){
    if(isOvered){
    var tp=e.clientY;
    var lft=e.clientX;
    document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv')[0].style.top=(tp-5)+"px";
    document.getElementsByClassName('mydiv')[0].style.left=(lft-75)+"px";
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.mydiv{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #f00;
    border: 2px solid #a00;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: move;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bolder;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 2px rgba(80,80,80,0.8);
}
</style>
</head>
<body onmousemove="dragme(event);">Helllllooooooooooooooooooo !!!!!!!!!
    <div class="mydiv" onmouseover="isOvered=true;" OnClick="isOvered=false;">
   <br /> 
   This is Draggable Div! Drags on Mouse over and Stops Drag on Click.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tell me If it helps you. Cheers !!